# Numerical analysis: prove that rate convergence p is the limit of log |en+1|/ log |en|

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

For the iterative method of $ X_{n+1} = g(X_n) $ with convergence rate of **p** and

$$
\lim_{n\to  \infty} \frac{ |e_{n+1}|}{|e_n|^{p} } = C
$$

I need to prove that:
$$
\lim_{n\to  \infty} \frac{ log |e_{n+1}|}{log|e_n| } = p
$$

when $e_n = |x-x_n|$ is the absolute error.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$
\lim_{n\to  \infty} \frac{ |e_{n+1}|}{|e_n|^{p} } = C
$$
which means $\lim_{n\to  \infty} \log{\frac{ |e_{n+1}|}{|e_n|^{p} } }= \log C$ by the continuity of $\log(x)$

so $\lim_{n\to  \infty} (\log |e_{n+1}|  - p\log |e_n|) = \log C$

Since $\log |e_n| \to -\infty$, we have 
$$\lim_{n\to  \infty}\dfrac{\log |e_{n+1}|  - p\log |e_n|}{\log |e_n|} = \dfrac{\log C}{-\infty} = 0$$

i.e.

$$\lim_{n\to  \infty}\dfrac{\log |e_{n+1}|  }{\log |e_n|} = p  $$